# Kendo Grid not binding data on any page after the first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid on a my *.cshtml page with server side paging. The reason for the server side bind was to only pull the amount of records and not all the data at once. It binds the data to the first page and shows the correct number pages for the grid but when I go to any other page, besides one, the data does not display.

[image: Page 1 and Page 2]

**.cshtml**

```
@(Html.Kendo()
        .Grid<Data.DTO.EmployeeDto>()
        .Name("EmployeeGrid")
        .Columns(cols =>
        {
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.Id).Title("ID").Hidden();
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.EmployeeNumber).Title("Employee ID").Width(100);
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.IsPayRunReady).Title("Status").Width(10).ClientTemplate("<span title='This employee is #= IsPayRunReady ? '': 'not '#payrun ready.' class='#= IsPayRunReady ? 'okICN-small' : 'alertICN-small'#'>#= IsPayRunReady ? '': 'Not' # #= IsPayRunReady ? 'P':'p'#ayrun ready</span>");
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.FirstName).Title("First Name").Width(100);
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.LastName).Title("Last Name").Width(100);
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.DateOfBirth).Title("DOB").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(100);
            cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("EmployeeDetailEdit", "EmployeeDetail") + "/#=Id#'>Edit</a>").Width(50);
            cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("EmployeeDetailRead", "EmployeeDetailRead") + "/#=Id#'>View</a>").Width(50);
            cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a class='k-button xxx' tag='#=Id#'>Delete</a>").Width(50);
        })
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(5))
        .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
        .Filterable()
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .Navigatable()            
        .Events(evt => evt.DataBound("afterGridLoaded"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .PageSize(10)
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(model => { model.Id(emp => emp.Id); })
            .Read(read => read.Action("EmployeeListPerPage", "EmployeeDetail"))
    )
)
```

**.cs**

```
public ActionResult EmployeeListPerPage([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        Dispose();
        EmployeeListRequest empList = new EmployeeListRequest();
        empList.PageNum = request.Page;
        empList.PageSize = request.PageSize;
        //empList.OrderBy = null; //request.Sorts.Any() ? "EmployeeNumber" : request.Sorts[0].Member;

        var dataSource = _payrollService.GetEmployeeListPerPage(empList);
        var model = new EmployeeListModel(dataSource);

        DataSourceResult result = model.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        result.Total = dataSource.Total;
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

There is no errors that are returned. I have notice that on the first binding the *DataSourceResult* is set but when you page it does not get set. Please see the below screenshot,

[image]

Could the browser be caching the **EmployeeListResponse** that is return to the var Model?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the results are skipped according to page number, not once, but twice.

Suppose you're querying for the second page:

- your `EmployeeListRequest` runs the query, selecting items 11-20
- The method `ToDataSourceResult` takes these 10 items, then runs the filter over them. It selects items 11-20 of these 10 items, which results in no items.

Your solution is to set up `EmployeeListRequest` so it does not filter on pages. Allow it to fetch everything, then get `ToDataSourceResult` to do the filtering.

You might be tempted to let `EmployeeListRequest` filter on pages, and then get `ToDataSourceResult` filter on everything else. This won't work if it is combined with any other filtering. Suppose you also filtered on "LastName = 'Smith', and there were 12 employees with that last name. The `EmployeeListRequest` would get any 10 employees (not just 'Smith'), and then the `ToDataSourceResult` would apply the "LastName" filter on just these 10 items. You need to apply the column filtering BEFORE you do the paging.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Shepherd, I'm planning to filter the data before the paging. This will be done in the `GetEmployees` method. Will do some more research and see if there is a way to get the paging to work without pulling all the data back. I'm using test data at the moment  that is sitting on 100 000 records, which is 25% of the live data table size.

Comment: @pchannon - At our company we use nHibernate, and I wrote a helper that translated a DataSourceRequest into an nHibernate query. It took a couple of days to get working, but it does work. Good luck!

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I understand and respect your solution but if we have 200k data what we can do. Maybe i wrong understand if i get 200k data and then filter it then i convert it to ToDatasourceResult this is also creates performance problem?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (request.Page != 1)
     request.Page = 1;

DataSourceResult result = model.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

Comment: Wow! It worked.. Can you explain this hack? How it's possible?